# Could not able to apply font in docx

Tags: reactjs, docx

I'm working on a React app where I'm using the docx package to generate Word documents. However, the font did not get applied

Here's the code snippet :

```
import React from "react";
import { Document, Packer, TextRun, Paragraph, AlignmentType } from "docx";
import { saveAs } from "file-saver";
import MontserratRegular from "../src/assets/Montserrat-Regular.ttf"; // Adjust the path
// import MontserratBold from "../src/assets/Montserrat-Bold.ttf"; // Adjust the path


class Report extends React.Component {


  generateReportWord = async () => {
    const sections = [
      ...this.generateFirstPage()
    ];

    const doc = new Document({
      sections: sections,
      fonts: [
        {
          family: "Montserrat",
          src: [
            {
              type: "embedded-opentype",
              data: MontserratRegular,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
      compatibility: {
        version: 15,
        doNotExpandShiftReturn: true,
      },
    });

    Packer.toBlob(doc).then((blob) => {
      saveAs(blob, "statement.docx");
    });
  }

  generateFirstPage = () => {
    return [
      {
        properties: {
        },
        children: [
          // Heading for the second page
          new Paragraph({
            children: [
              new TextRun({
                text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nun",
                font: {
                  name: "Montserrat",
                  src: MontserratRegular,
                },
                color: "0f0c00",
                size: 50,
                bold: true,
                alignment: AlignmentType.CENTER
              })
            ]
          }),
        ]
      }
    ];
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.generateReportWord}>Generate Document</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Report;
```

I've checked the documentation and reviewed my code, but I can't seem to identify what's causing this issue. I'm trying to apply the Montserrat font to the document, but something seems to be going wrong.

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue with the docx package? Could someone help me identify what might be causing this error and how I can resolve it?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!